# How to set ItemsSource of ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here I have defined my data *myListOfEmployeeObjects*:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public List<Employee> myListOfEmployeeObjects;

    public App ()
    {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee () {
            FirstName = "Max",
            LastName = "Mustermann",
            Twitter = "@fake1"
        };
        Employee emp2 = new Employee () {
            FirstName = "Evy",
            LastName = "Mustermann",
            Twitter = "@fake2"
        };
        myListOfEmployeeObjects = new List<Employee> {
            emp1, emp2
        };
        MainPage = new NavigationPage (new EmployeeListPage ());
    }
}
```

Than I have my XAML where I set the `ItemsSource`:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"
                IsVisible="false"
                ItemsSource="{x:Static local:App.myListOfEmployeeObjects}"
                ItemSelected="EmployeeListOnItemSelected">
```

Should this work? Because I get

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Type App not found in xmlns

```
public partial class EmployeeListPage : ContentPage {

    private ListView listView;

    private void InitializeComponent() {
        this.LoadFromXaml(typeof(EmployeeListPage)); // here the exception is thrown
        listView = this.FindByName <ListView>("listView");
    }
}
```

How can I set the `ItemsSource` of my XAML?

**Edit:**

Now I tried the suggestion from [*user2425632*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2425632/user2425632) and it works if I do the following changes:

1. Adding `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloXamarinFormsWorld;assembly=HelloXamarinFormsWorld"` to my XAML file

It now looks like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloXamarinFormsWorld;assembly=HelloXamarinFormsWorld"
             x:Class="HelloXamarinFormsWorld.EmployeeListPage"
             Title="Employee List">
    <ContentPage.Content>
```

Of course you have to change the names so that it suits to your project.

2. Showing list view

I removed the `IsVisible` and the `ItemSelected`.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Static local:App.myListOfEmployeeObjects}">
```

3. Make everything static

It has to be static, otherwise you get

> No static member found for local:App.myListOfEmployeeObjects

```
public static List<Employee> myListOfEmployeeObjects { private set; get; }

public static void GetAllEmployees(){
    Employee emp1 = new Employee () {
        FirstName = "Max",
        LastName = "Mustermann",
        Twitter = "@fake1"
    };
    Employee emp2 = new Employee () {
        FirstName = "Eva",
        LastName = "Mustermann",
        Twitter = "@fake2"
    };
    myListOfEmployeeObjects = new List<Employee> {
        emp1, emp2
    };
}

public App ()
{
    GetAllEmployees ();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage (new EmployeeListPage ());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I haven't actually gotten around to doing this myself but from reading the documentation I have a suggestion which may be worth you trying.

```
ItemsSource="{x:Static local:App.myListOfEmployeeObjects}"
```

In your xaml you've said that the source is static but looking at your .cs file it isn't. Try the following:

```
public static List<Employee> myListOfEmployeeObjects { private set; get; }
```

and then try and set the object using a static function, eg.:

```
static App() {
    myListOfEmployeeObjects = something;
}
```

Then the list should be viewable on the page.

I used the following links which you may find useful:

[Xamarin documentation on data-binding](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/data_binding_basics/)

[Example cs code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/XAMLSamples/xamlsamples/xamlsamples/NamedColor.cs)

[Example xaml code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/XAMLSamples/xamlsamples/xamlsamples/ListViewDemoPage.xaml)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the solution for your problem. I had the same issue and I added this line in EmployeeListPage.xaml :

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace;assembly=YourAssembly"
```

You'll get the name of assembly in the properties of your project and the namespace in any page.cs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ObservableCollections`. This type of collection, notifies when changes are made to it.

In your code:

**.cs:**

```
public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged //Note this INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<Employee> _myListOfEmployeeObjects;
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> ObservableEmployees
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myListOfEmployeeObjects == null) LoadEmployees();
            return _myListOfEmployeeObjects;
        }
        set
        {
            _myListOfEmployeeObjects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ObservableEmployees");
        }
    }

     private void LoadEmployees()
    {
        // Necessary stuff to load employees
        ObservableEmployees = new ObservableCollection<Employees>();
        ....
    }
```

You must add a `DataContext = this` in your default constructor:

```
public YourClass()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

And then, add the necessary method to `NotifyOnPropertyChanged`:

```
 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
 {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
 }
```

In your .xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"
    IsVisible="false"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObservableEmployees, ElementName=EmployeesWindow, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
    ItemSelected="EmployeeListOnItemSelected">
```

In `ElementName=EmployeesWindow`, the `EmployeesWindow` is your main Window `x:Name`.

```
<Window ...
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"                      
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Name="EmployeesWindow" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll try it out. Would it be possible to use a normal list as I did? Or can this only be done with `ObservableCollections`? [Here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/XAMLSamples/xamlsamples/xamlsamples/ListViewDemoPage.xaml) only a static `IEnumerable` has been used ...

Comment: I think bindings will be only seen with `ObservableCollections`. Try this code, and if it works, try to change it with a regular list as you have. They are not difficult. The same like lists :)

Comment: Now I tried your code (see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6gZFUM)). Some things are not clear for me. 1. What is `InitializeComponent()`? 2. What is `DataContext`? I commented them out because otherwise I get an build error. `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; ` was missing and I added it. 3. What is my main window? My main window is not in XAML. Perhaps are you talking from WPF, because the Xamarin version does look different. I removed it from the .xaml. When I try running the code I get *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*.

Comment: The `InitializeComponent()` is auto-generated when you first create an WPF  project, so you don't have to modify or write it. Just look for it and add the `DataContext` line after.
The `DataContext` tells the application that, any data change, will be shared in the same context.
Anyways... can you post full code please? Add `.xaml` and `.cs`.

Comment: I think WPF is different than the Xamarin approach. DataContext = BindingContext? Nevertheless, [.cs](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6gZFUM), [.xaml](http://www.codeshare.io/cdOGq). Sorry, I can't use many other services because the webfilter here blocks everything ...